# R: Rename column of a list element with value from column

Tags: r, list

I have a list of data frames.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:4), var1 = c(4:7))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(11:14), var1 = c(14:17))
ldf <- list(df1, df2)

head(ldf)
[[1]]
  ID var1
1  1    4
2  2    5
3  3    6
4  4    7

[[2]]
  ID var1
1 11   14
2 12   15
3 13   16
4 14   17
```

I need to rename one particular column with the value of its first name;
e.g. for the dummy data I want to rename the second column of each dataframe with the
value of the first line of the third column.

```
[[1]]
  ID    1
1  1    4
2  2    5
3  3    6
4  4    7

[[2]]
  ID   11
1 11   14
2 12   15
3 13   16
4 14   17
```

I tried something like:

```
ldf <- ldf %>% map(~ rename(., ID[1] = var1))
```

That obviously won't work.

Seems simple, yet I need help.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lapply` :

```
lapply(ldf, function(x) {names(x)[2] <- x[1, 1];x})

#[[1]]
#  ID 1
#1  1 4
#2  2 5
#3  3 6
#4  4 7

#[[2]]
#  ID 11
#1 11 14
#2 12 15
#3 13 16
#4 14 17
```

Or if you prefer `map` :

```
map(ldf, ~{names(.x)[2] <- .x[1, 1];.x})
```

Here `names(x)[2]` represents 2nd column, and `x[1, 1]` extracts value from 1st row, 1st column.

Comment: Thank you that worked fine. Is it also possible to do that by using the column names?

Comment: Do you mean using `ID` to replace values instead of `x[1, 1]` ? In that case you can use `x$ID[1]` ?